# need some thing weird to do in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the elements from the database where the status begins from either w or c.. i tried this query but the page gets blank..

```
$test1=mysql_query("select * from railways where status like('w%') || like('c%')");
```

how is this query written in that case???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM railways WHERE SUBSTR(status,1,1) IN ('w','c')
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with

```
select * from railways where status like('w%') or status like('c%')
```